# Create SQL job to send email in Excel format

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am not skilled in SQL and need some help.  I have a SQL2005 server and I created a job to send an email with a CSV attachment. My job runs fine but I need the end result to be an Excel file in either .xls or .xlsx format.

Here is the code for the job:

```
USE My_DB
GO

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
    @profile_name = 'DBMail'
    ,@recipients =  'me@my_org.com' 
    ,@copy_recipients = ''
    ,@execute_query_database = 'My_DB'
    ,@query = 'exec MY_RPT_MonthlyWIPSp'
    --@body =@bodyContent
    ,@subject = 'Monthly WIP Report'
    ,@attach_query_result_as_file = 1
    ,@query_attachment_filename = 'result.csv'
    ,@query_result_separator=',',@query_result_width =32767
    ,@query_result_no_padding=1;
```

What do I need to change and where to get the data to come out in the format I need?  Do I have to modify my SP?

Comment: You might want to google 'why not use SQL 2005' I am sure there are lots of reasons you are still using it.... The reasons not to are significant.

Comment: Unfortunately I am stuck with SQL 2005 for a few more months until we can get a legacy system upgraded.

Comment: Learned something new and updated my answer.  If you **REALLY** need to get to Excel, it would provide an option, particularly if you have existing PowerShell skills.

Comment: Fairly easy to use SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS), which comes with SQL Server from 2005 and up. Create a report, and create a subscription to the report, which you can specify as Excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr** I don't think what you want is an option with the tools you have available.

I do not believe it is possible with SQL 2005, to actually have your data export as .xls or .xlsx format.

Over the years I have tried with several different tools to do just this.  I did not have the option to select different tools.

In anycase, for most window devices opening a .csv file will open it in Excel.  Normally the .csv file is physically smaller then it would be as .xls or .xlsx, so there are some benefits to keeping it .csv.

Once you have the .csv file you can open it with Excel and save it as .xls or .xlsx.  I think that is your only option.

**Update** This is outside the parameters of the question but worthy of mention: There is a PowerShell module [dfinke/ImportExcel](https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel) that will allow you to convert table data to Excel even if you don't have Excel on the machine, and put in a folder.  I saw this in a demo of [Dbatools](https://dbatools.io/) and it looks really interesting.

Comment: Looks like that is the case, on my tests on SQL Server 2014 SP2, the .xls attachment mail failed, the .xlsx mail succeeded but the file was 'damaged' and unable to open.

Comment: @James I found that sending the file as a .csv did not work the way I needed it; however, you made me think of another solution.  I changed the delimiter from comma to tab and the file opens with the data formatted properly.

Comment: @KevinH I have done similar as well when my data had comma's in it.  I have also found tabs in my data (i.e. comments of a text field) There are other options for delimiter it has been a few years, but I think I used ^ (Caret , upper case 6) when I found tabs in my data.